# PHP Arrays Stacking with Call class?

Tags: php, oop

Okay, so I'm trying to create a `Call` class on top of my Controller, Model and View. However, when I set the the class to the array inside the `Call` class, it seems to be stacking the arrays on top of one another (in the order that they are called), instead of putting them in order one by one.

Here's what I mean:

```
array(1) {
  ["Controller"]=>
  object(Controller)#2 (1) {
    ["classes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Controller_Pages"]=>
      object(Controller_Pages)#3 (1) {
        ["classes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["View"]=>
          object(View)#4 (2) {
            ["params"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["Testing"]=>
              string(7) "a test."
              ["lolni"]=>
              string(7) "a test."
            }
            ["classes"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to be stacking them in the order that I am calling them.

Here's the Call class:

```
<?php

class Call {

    public $classes = Array();

    public function __call($name, $args)  {

        if(!is_object($this->classes[$name])) {

            require_once 'Slave/' . str_replace('_', '/', $name) . '.php';

            $this->classes[$name] = new $name();

            // to confirm that they are being stacked in the order they are being called

            echo $name . "\n\n";

        }

        return $this->classes[$name]; 

    } 

    public function dump() {

        var_dump($this->classes);

    }

}
```

So inside the Controller, for example, you'd call a class like this:

```
<?php

// Class -> Function

$this->Model()->query();
```

Here's the source if you want to take a look:

http://joshfoskett.com/View/Call_Issue

So the question is, how would I get the array to look like this?

```
array(3) {
  ["Controller"]=>
  object(Controller)#1 (1) {
    ["classes"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [0]=>
  object(Controller_Pages)#2 (1) {
    ["classes"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["View"]=>
  object(View)#3 (2) {
    ["params"]=>
    NULL
    ["classes"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Incase someone references this later, here is what I did to solve the issue.

I basically set `$classes` to `static`, and referenced the classes with `self::`:

```
<?php

class Call {

    public static $classes = Array();

    public function __call($name, $args)  {

        if(!is_object(self::$classes[$name])) {

            require_once 'Slave/' . str_replace('_', '/', $name) . '.php';

            self::$classes[$name] = new $name();

        }

        return self::$classes[$name]; 

    }

    public function dump() {

        var_dump(self::$classes);

    }

}
```

This way, the class that extends to `Call` isn't using `$this->classes` on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is really no problem.

What's happening here is simple, `Controller` extends `Call`, and so does `Controller_Pages`.
So, when you do `$this->class();` inside `Controller` or `Controller_Pages`, the method will act as if it was from Controller thus using `$this->classes` as if it was from `Controller`.

I don't really see the problem of this happening, as long as the code is sexy and efficient, it's ok to me.